# Xorg high GPU memory usage - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, graphics, xorg, gpu

Gnome Shell + Xorg take up to ~ 1.5GB of my GPU Memory.

Is this normal? Is there an easy way to reduce it?

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.39       Driver Version: 460.39       CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Graphics Device     Off  | 00000000:2B:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 30%   33C    P3    33W / 170W |   1857MiB / 12050MiB |      2%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A     17004      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                168MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     17238      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg               1171MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     17351      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell              490MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     19632      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            2MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     19730      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            2MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     20241      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            2MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     20416      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            2MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     20532      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            2MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     20724      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            2MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I would like to use my GPU memory for Deep Learning and thus would like to try to reduce the usage.

Appreciate any pointers here.

Comment: Sorry for bumping in here without being able to help, but what command gives this output?

Comment: the command is: `nvidia-smi`